# C - How to use multiple functions in macros?

Tags: c, webserver

Currently building a simple webserver in c.
To improve the code I want to use makros and spefically I want to use multiple functions inside a single makro to print an error message and quit the program afterwards.

The following code works without pedantic error messages but I would like to know why ISO-C forbids this or where my error is.

Compiler info:

```sh
gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror error_makro.c
```

Code:

```c
#define CHECK(x,m) ((x) < 0) ? ({perror(m); exit(1);}) : (NULL)

void createWebSocket(simpleWebServer *self){

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;


    CHECK(getaddrinfo(NULL, self->port, &hints, &res), "getaddrinfo");

    if((self->serverSocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)) < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(bind(self->serverSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0){
        perror("bind");
        exit(3);
    }
    if(listen(self->serverSocket, BACKLOG) == -1){
        perror("listen");
        exit(4);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);  
}
```

Error message:

```sh
error_makro.c: In function ‘main’:
error_makro.c:6:32: error: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
    6 | #define CHECK(x,m) ((x) < 0) ? ({perror(m); exit(1);}) : (NULL)
      |                                ^
error_makro.c:11:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK’
   11 |     CHECK(-1, "test");
      |     ^~~~~
error_makro.c:6:56: error: ISO C forbids conditional expr with only one void side [-Wpedantic]
    6 | #define CHECK(x,m) ((x) < 0) ? ({perror(m); exit(1);}) : (NULL)
      |                                                        ^
error_makro.c:11:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK’
   11 |     CHECK(-1, "test");
      |     ^~~~~
```

Comment: You are abusing the ternary operator as an `if` replacement. That looks rather awful. Why don't you just put an `if` statement into the macro?

Comment: Do you intent to use that macro in some function arguments or assignments or any other place where you need an expression instead of a statement?

Comment: Currently I just want to use the macro as shown above. So using an expression is not neccessary for me. I simply did not know any better way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define CHECK(x,m) ((x) < 0) ? ({perror(m); exit(1);}) : ({(NULL);})
```

will work:

https://godbolt.org/z/Kxed3b55r

Both sides have the same type `void`. You cannot use `-pedantic` as compile time flag, because `ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions`.

In this case I would suggest:

```
#define CHECK(x,m) do { if ((x) < 0) {perror(m); exit(1);} } while (0)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/srExevfGT

Answer (score 0):

In standard C, the `;` marks the end of an expression. Therefore a parenthesis cannot contain a `;`, since syntax-wise a both `(` and `)` of the parenthesis needs to be inside a full expression.

The `({ ... })` is a "statement expression", a non-standard GNU extension that allows multiple expressions ending with `;` inside it and at the same time returning the result of the last expression.

In `-std=c17 -pedantic` mode, gcc turns into a compliant C compiler so all GNU extensions are disabled.

Please note that standard C can likely be used instead of these "statement expressions". You can often chain a bunch of function calls using the comma operator: `(perror(m), exit(1))` - this too returns the result of the last (right-most) sub-expresion.

Better yet, use an actual function, which is probably the most correct solution in this case.

Comment: Calling a function for each if-statement would result in multiple "jumps" in assembly. Would this still be the best practice in this case, thinking about a webserver?

Comment: Functions of this size are usually inlined: https://godbolt.org/z/31EbYnfb5 no call to `CHECK` in `main`, but directly the `perror` call. Even with a variable instead of a constant: https://godbolt.org/z/v7jPPvcKs

Comment: @apocs If the reason for using this macro is performance, then something has gone horribly wrong in the project.

Comment: @Lundin Why shouldn't I program something to be as performant as possible?

Comment: @apocs Because this is from the middle of a code handling with massive bottlenecks in the form of socket I/O? Trying to optimize a few branches here and there won't matter, such optimization attempts are focusing on the wrong things.